# How to pass live audio url to Google Speech to Text API

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I have a url to live audio recording that I'm trying to transcribe using Google Speech to Text API. I am using an example code from the Cloud Speech to Text API. However, the problem is that when I pass the live url I do not receive any output. Below is the relevant portion of my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
import io
import os
import time
import requests
import numpy as np
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]= "app_creds.json"

def get_stream():

    stream = urlopen('streamurl')

    duration = 60
    begin = datetime.now()
    duration = timedelta(seconds=duration)

    while datetime.now() - begin < duration:

        data = stream.read(8000)

        return data

def transcribe_streaming():
    """Streams transcription of the given audio file."""
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    content = get_stream()

    # In practice, stream should be a generator yielding chunks of audio data.
    stream = [content]
    requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=chunk)
                for chunk in stream)

    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US')

    streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(config=config)

    # streaming_recognize returns a generator.
    responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)

    for response in responses:
        # Once the transcription has settled, the first result will contain the
        # is_final result. The other results will be for subsequent portions of
        # the audio.
        for result in response.results:
            print('Finished: {}'.format(result.is_final))
            print('Stability: {}'.format(result.stability))
            alternatives = result.alternatives
            # The alternatives are ordered from most likely to least.
            for alternative in alternatives:
                print('Confidence: {}'.format(alternative.confidence))
                print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
```

Comment: Did you actually obtained the credentials from Google API console?

Comment: I did - ive just update the code with most recent changes. That didn't work either. Im still getting no output.

Comment: `stream = urlopen('streamurl')` - not clear at all. What is the format of the input audio? Is it single channel, 16KHz, linear 16 bit PCM? If it's something else, then surely Google can return empty result.

Comment: Ahh then thats probably the issue. The format of the input is a single channel, 16 bit PCM. However, the feed is encoded at a sample rate of 22050 Hz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending audio to the Google Speech service, make sure that the service object setup matches the audio encoding. In your particular case

```py
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    language_code='en-US')
```

corresponds to single channel, 16KHz, linear 16 bit PCM encoding. See the [list of other supported encodings](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding#audio-encodings) if you need to transcribe audio in different formats.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve ("http://www.example.com/songs/mp3.mp3", "mp3.mp3")
```

(for Python 3+ use import `urllib.request` and `urllib.request.urlretrieve`)

Answer (score 0):

A part of my code I used a while back, I don't know if that may help:

```
def live_recognize_loop(self):
        client = self.client

        def is_running():
            return self.recording

        while self.recording:
            with MicrophoneStream(RATE, CHUNK) as stream:
                audio_generator = stream.generator(is_running)
                requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content) for content in audio_generator)
                responses = client.streaming_recognize(client.custom_streaming_config, requests)

                responses_iterator = iter(responses)
                while self.recording:
                    try:
                        response = next(responses_iterator)
                    except StopIteration:
                        break
                    except OutOfRange:
                        # Exception 400 - Exceeded maximum allowed stream duration of 65 seconds.
                        self.user_display(self.intermediateFrame.GetMessageText())
                        break  # Start over
                    except ServiceUnavailable as e:
                        # Exception 503 - Getting metadata from plugin failed
                        self.log("{0} - NOT RECOGNIZED - {1}\n".format(self.getDate(), e))
                        break
                    except ResourceExhausted as e:
                        break
                    except GoogleAPICallError as e:
                        break

                    if response.results:
                        result = response.results[0]
                        if result.alternatives:
                            transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript
                            self.intermediateFrame.SetMessageText(transcript)
                            if not result.is_final:
                                self.intermediateFrame.Display()
                                # print(transcript)
                            else:
                                self.user_display(transcript)
                                self.intermediateFrame.Display(False)
                                self.intermediateFrame.SetMessageText("")
                                #print("\t\t FINAL: %s" % transcript)
                                break  # Start over
```

MicrophoneStream class

```
from __future__ import division

import pyaudio
from six.moves import queue


class MicrophoneStream(object):
    """Opens a recording stream as a generator yielding the audio chunks."""
    def __init__(self, rate, chunk):
        self._rate = rate
        self._chunk = chunk

        # Create a thread-safe buffer of audio data
        self._buff = queue.Queue()
        self.closed = True

    def __enter__(self):
        self._audio_interface = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self._audio_stream = self._audio_interface.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            # The API currently only supports 1-channel (mono) audio
            channels=1, rate=self._rate,
            input=True, frames_per_buffer=self._chunk,
            # Run the audio stream asynchronously to fill the buffer object.
            # This is necessary so that the input device's buffer doesn't
            # overflow while the calling thread makes network requests, etc.
            stream_callback=self._fill_buffer,
        )

        self.closed = False

        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self._audio_stream.stop_stream()
        self._audio_stream.close()
        self.closed = True
        # Signal the generator to terminate so that the client's
        # streaming_recognize method will not block the process termination.
        self._buff.put(None)
        self._audio_interface.terminate()

    def _fill_buffer(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status_flags):
        """Continuously collect data from the audio stream, into the buffer."""
        self._buff.put(in_data)
        return None, pyaudio.paContinue

    def generator(self, is_running=None):
        while not self.closed:
            # Use a blocking get() to ensure there's at least one chunk of
            # data, and stop iteration if the chunk is None, indicating the
            # end of the audio stream.
            chunk = self._buff.get()
            if callable(is_running) and not is_running():
                return
            if chunk is None:
                return
            data = [chunk]

            # Now consume whatever other data's still buffered.
            while True:
                try:
                    chunk = self._buff.get(block=False)
                    if chunk is None:
                        return
                    data.append(chunk)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break

            yield b''.join(data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same behaviour - I'm not receiving any output from the Speech to text API

Comment: So maybe it's a microphone issue. Does it recognize your speech?

Comment: So the input is not my microphone, but a live audio recording from a url